# Moksha as continuous Samadhi?

Tags: moksha, samadhi

Is there anything in any scripture that you know of that would say or imply moksha can be described as permanent samadhi on brahman or on parabrahman - as continuous abiding in/as Brahman? Or any other type of permanent samadhi?

Comment: You can try searching in commentaries on yoga-sutras. There are mentions of two types of samadhi as means of liberation.

Comment: Samadhi has savikalpa samadhi nirvikalpa samadhi. You come back to world from savikalpa. Nirvikalpa you abide in self. No return.

Comment: @PrabrahmanJyoti people come back from Nirvikalpa Samadhi, for eg: Ramakrishna Paramahamsa

Comment: The fact that people come back from a samadhi doesn’t necessarily mean that those at moksha do so. Also, those who have achieved moksha may go deeper into it at dedicated times. Im not saying thats right, just a possibility for the above

Comment: @MrGreenGold yes as I wrote below: a “state of quietude, in which, identified with Brahman, he has constant enjoyment of the Bliss Absolute, the One without a second.” sounds a lot like samadhi. But idk.

Comment: That is the entire purport of the Upanishads...It is said everywhere in the Upanishads. You might try to do a search on this forum. This questions and similar questions has been asked previously.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda thanks glad to hear that. In the answer below and its comments one knowledgeable person is saying otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Moksha is not continuous Samadhi. A person who has realized Brahman in Samadhi stays in that state of identification with Brahman regardless of what he does. It does not matter whether he is in samadhi or not.

> To the sage who has realized Brahman, the mind, which is the cause of
> unreal fancies, becomes perfectly tranquil. This verily is his state
> of quietude, in which, identified with Brahman, **he has constant
> enjoyment of the Bliss Absolute,** the One without a second.

**Vivekacudamani 526**

> To the man who has realized his own nature, and drinks the undiluted
> bliss of the Self, there is nothing more exhilarating than the
> quietude that comes of a state of desireless.

**Vivekacudamani 527**

> The illumined sage, whose only pleasure is in the Self, ever lives at
> ease, whether going or staying, sitting or lying, or in any other
> condition.

**Vivekacudamani 528**

> The noble soul who has perfectly realized the Truth, and whose
> mind-functions meet with no obstruction, no more depends upon
> conditions of place, time, posture, direction, moral disciplines,
> objects of meditation and so forth. What regulative conditions can
> there be in knowing one's own Self?

**Vivekacudamani 529**

Comment: Pradip I think you are wrong here, the constant experience of bliss here is Samadhi. There are two different types Savikalpa and Nirvikalpa. People who have realised will always be in Savikalpa Samadhi, that is why they are always blissful, that's the mechanism IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply and verses .  However, a “state of quietude, in which, identified with Brahman, he has constant enjoyment of the Bliss Absolute, the One without a second.” **sounds a lot like samadhi**. But idk. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: @MrGreenGold,@Al Brown, Yes, identification with Brahman has features that are common with Samadhi. However, this experience is not samadhi. In Samadhi the entire mind is withdrawn from the world and focused on an object. In the state of Samadhi it is not possible to teach while Ramana Maharsi or Sri Ramakrishna did teach. As regards Savikalpa Samadhi it is true that such a person will continue to have an experience of divine forms but such a person will not always withdraw his mind from the world.

Comment: In samadhi there is no mind. Mindless state. Mind doesn't function.  There's no focus. No concentration nothing. Mind freezes. The complete emptiness where the state cannot be described its samadhi. Remember as long as you describe experiences of dhyan the mind is in operation.  In samadhi there's no mind.